# find command to find php files but exclude a certain directory

Tags: linux, centos, find

How do I run a find command to find php files but I exclude a folder i.e. /usr/local/bin?

Answer (score 2):

Prune it.

```
find some/dir \( -type d -path some/dir/some/other/dir -prune -o -name '*.php' -print \)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the find command in linux to do this. Something like this should work.

```
find / \! -path "/usr/local/bin/*" -name "*.php"
```